# Anfis with sugeno fuzzy model using matlab

Tags: neural-network, matlab, fuzzy-logic

I am implementing a ANFIS model with hydrid training method. I have 13 inputs that maps to one output. I framed rules with respect to my system. When I  train data, i get the below error:

> Number of output MF's is not equal to number of rules

Any clues about where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quote from the [Fuzzy Logic Toolbox User's Guide](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/fuzzy/):

> Constraints of anfis: 
>   anfis is much more complex than the fuzzy
>   inference systems discussed so far, and is not available for all of
>   the fuzzy inference system options. Specifically, anfis only supports
>   Sugeno-type systems, and these must have the following properties:
>   * **Have no rule sharing. Different rules cannot share the same output
>   membership function**, namely the number of output membership functions
>   must be equal to the number of rules.

The ANFIS model structure should therefore look like this:
[image]

FYI the error comes from the following code snippet:

```
/* output MF no. must be the same as rule no. */
if (fis->output[0]->mf_n != fis->rule_n) {
    fisFreeFisNode(fis);
    PRINTF("Number of output MF's is not equal to number of rules -->\n");
    fisError("Parameter sharing in FIS is not allowed!");
}
```

Comment: Great!yup,thanx for notification, i did share the Mf,that led to error! Its Resolved now!

Comment: What if you actually need the shared parameters (creating a different output for every combination creates a snowball/avalanche effect to the number of outputs produced). Is there any alternative training in that case?